# Parsing JSONObject in javascript or Jquery

Tags: java, jquery, json

Hi friends i have a `java.util.Map` object in Ajax method like this..

```
Map<String,List<String>> sm = new TreeMap<>();

    List<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();
    str.add("val1");
    str.add("val2");
    str.add("val3");
    str.add("val4");

    sm.put("shift1", str);
    sm.put("shift2", str);
    sm.put("shift3", str);
    sm.put("shift4", str);

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(sm);

    response.getWriter().print(json);
```

In run time Map elements will be increase or decrease 
according to map elements I have to generate table

This is Ajax call.. I don't know how to parse that Map object and dynamically generate the table in javascript.

Please show me how.

Comment: is this code even compiling? how can you pass a java type into the `JSONObject` constructor?

Comment: another thing - each `put` call effectively overrides the previous assignment. is this the actual code you're using?

Comment: ya 100% it will compile.. `JSONObject` is Java class..

Comment: @Eliran Malka i written only sample data not actual data

Answer (score 0):

I am just answering your question. I don't know java and also i don't understand the details you gave above. If I am wrong, I am sorry and kindly ignore it.

To parse the string to object

> In the jQuery, $.parseJSON(string);
>
> In js, JSON.parse(string);

I hope this will help U. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
var json = $.parseJSON( jsonString );

// This one wouldn't be supported in old browsers
json = JSON.parse( jsonString );
```

Additionally, you could, in Java, respond with the Content-Type `application/json` and then in the jQuery AJAX you will receive the JSON already parsed for you.

Of course this will not happen if you specifically configure your jQuery AJAX call to receive an plain text, or HTML, or other content-type response.
For more reference, [see here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings), at the `dataType` setting.